# What is the minimum RAM required for Pokemon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

While poking around on Pokemon Go's [Supported devices](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices), it lists some specs required for Android and iOS devices. I'm particularly interested in Android devices, but I do not see a minimum/recommended RAM listed on their site.

> - Android 4.4 to Android 6.0.1  (Android N will not supported until the
>     official Android release)
> - Preferred resolution of 720x1280 pixels
>     (Not optimized for tablet)
> - Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or
>     4G)
> - GPS and Location Services
> - Intel CPUs are not supported

My device is a [Samsung Galaxy Express Prime](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_express_prime-8022.php), which has a 1.5GB RAM and Quad-Core processor. It runs fine for the most part, but a majority of the features heavily lags and are sluggish while I've seen the same features run smooth on other devices.

What is the minimum/recommended RAM for Pokemon Go to run more smoothly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google play store recommends 2GB of ram or more but fewer should still be able to run it but could lag as you've noticed. However another reason for the lag could simply due to a poor connection since the game definitely runs better over wifi.

[Source](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

While Android 4.4 OS system's minimal RAM can be only 512mb, it would definitely not run Pokemon GO smoothly, if it would run in the first place.

In your case, I don't think *Random Access Memory* is the problem here. Your processor would more likely cause some lag.

Most Android devices have 2GB of RAM and that seems to do just fine amongst many players.

Comment: Entry level phones tend to come with 1GB RAM.