# Will the Samsung Galaxy Nexus run Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it possible to play Pokémon Go on an old phone like this?

What about if I install Lineage OS to play with Pokémon go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your device would not be able to run the game (at least not in any playable fashion) If you visit the [Pokemon Go Store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en) while on the device, it will likely tell you as much.

---

Your device is a [Galaxy Nexus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus), here's it's specifications (the ones that matter):

- **Operating System:** Stock: Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich), upgradeable to 4.3 (Jelly Bean)
- **Display Resolution:** 1280×720 (720p)
- **RAM**: 1 GB

Now, according to Pokemon Go's [stated requirements:](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=troubleshooting&f=supported-devices), and an earlier question here: [What is the minimum RAM required for Pokemon GO?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275701/28182), here's what you'd need to run Pokemon Go:

- **Operating System:** Android 4.4+
- **Display Resolution:** 1280x720
- **RAM**: At least 2GB, if not more

The Galaxy Nexus does not meet the minimum RAM or OS requirements to play the game. Furthermore, rooting the device and installing another OS will likely not work either as [rooted devices are apparently not supported](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=troubleshooting&f=supported-devices) either - even if you did manage to get it installed it still wouldn't meet the RAM requirement.

You should look at upgrading to a newer device.

Comment: I have tried and gives me always authentication failed, is it because I haven't a SIM inside?

Comment: @Alessandro If you're not hooked up to wifi, then yes. You will need either Wifi or a SIM card with a data plan (2G, 3G etc). But I think that's the least of your worries

Comment: @Robotnik I should point out that the 2GB requirement is most certainly heavily exaggerated. Considering that I am currently in my 4th year of studying Computer Science, I can say with decent approximation that it shouldn't be needing 2GB to run.That's more likely a *harddrive* space requirement as there shouldn't be a very large heap space or stack space requirement. As for the code of the program being too large the [swap space](https://www.google.com/search?q=swap+space+management+in+operating+system&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtrqyk1YnWAhXqz4MKHXdsCt8Q1QIIoQEoAg&biw=1366&bih=636) will deal with that.

Comment: @Typhon Mobile OSes are not desktop OSes. The differences are... complicated to explain.  You're talking about the phone as if it is a desktop.  It's not.

Comment: @Nelson Nothing I've written there has to do with the OS aside from a swap space and even if that didn't exist (for some absurdly stupid reason) there's still the fact that the program's code can be taken in and out of memory at virtually no cost. It can just be loaded back in from the file it is stored in. If the phone's don't at least do *that*, then we're dealing with a system that's downright inefficient.

Comment: @Nelson Different types of memory structures only has to do with the programs are coded. It has nothing to do with the OS nor does it even enforce that they be used in that manner. It's just a convention most people use. IF (big if) someone came up with some superior method of organizing the different memory structures there would be nothing stopping their program from doing that. The OS only controls which physical memory addresses they have access to, not what the program decides to put there.

Comment: Pokémon Go is not well optimized at all.  If the netcode is any indicator, I'd say Niantic makes a first pass at making something work and never really revisits it unless there's a security hole.  After having played on multiple devices with vastly different play experiences, I would strongly suggest at least 2GB of RAM if you don't want to be constantly frustrated while playing this game.

Answer (score -2):

*It might actually run quite well, barring the OS incompatibility.*

Since Robotnik's answer doesn't go into a lot of detail I'll fill in a few more details about what will likely happen. First off, we must consider that programs consist (in general) of four main chunks of memory.

- Code
- Static Space
- Heap Space
- Stack/Function Space

The first one is fairly obvious and straightforward. It is the compiled binary code. The second one is the static space. It contains any values global to the entire program (such as your player data). The heap space contains dynamically allocated memory. Uhhh... it basically contains complex structures and objects such as charts, trees, lists of arbitrary length, etc. Finally, the stack space contains the data needed to perfom operations upon data. It holds the local data for these operations.

Considering this, let's examine Pokemon Go from an external perspective:

- Pings an external database for Pokemon data
- Works as a naive/crude map application
- Rarely does any heavy numerical and/or logical operations

Therefore, I conclude that it likely has a very small stack space requirement and heap space requirement. This will change when 3D models of things are loaded in. However, those will be minimal and only happen when catching a Pokemon. Note however that in conventional computer graphics points in a 3D model consist of 4 8-byte doubles. Based on this, it would take $\frac {2^30}{8} = 134217728$ vertices to hit the 2GB requirement. In fact, it likely won't even hit the 1GB requirement for your phone. 3D models are just polygons in space. Nobody is going to make a 3D model with 67 million points in it by hand. You don't gain any extra precision or beauty.

So this rules out pretty much the entire stack and heap spaces as being the culprit of the 2GB requirement. The static space is rarely very large (mostly as a programming convention).

**The RAM requirement is a direct result of the size of the code itself**

Considering the number of Pokemon in existence this is likely true. That and all the textural, polygonal and behavioral data needed for captures will build up when you have hundreds out there.

> So will your phone be able to handle it?

It all depends on whether or not your phone has a very specific feature. If it doesn't, then the app will just crash (so feel no bad qualms about trying to emulate it in a proper OS environment so long as you do so *legally*).

The app will be able to handle itself so long as you have a decent hardrive and what is known as a [swap space](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/swap-file-swap-space-or-pagefile). Since the bulk of the data is likely Pokemon info, the game will just grab it from the swap space when needed. Normally a high degree of swapping causes a type of lag called *thrashing*. However, in this case that is unlikely to occur as you aren't needing to consistently swap. You just need to swap a tiny bit out to load something like a battle or an item menu.

Conclusion:

> Your phone can run the app. It might run slow at times and it might be altogether incompatible. However, the memory requirement should be fine so long as you aren't someone who likes to keep their phone chock full of photos. Tbh though, that's a horrible practice. Keep in mind that this does not examine the OS incompatibility. With this being an online game, there is the high possibility that OS incompatibility could cause problems. **Definitely** make sure that you handle that somehow if you choose to run this on your phone. Otherwise you risk screwing up your phone. However, you can at least rest assured that your hardware can probably handle it given a decent swap space.

Comment: Very good answer the phone have only pokemon go installed, it is completly free, if there are some hardware problems I think the app crash but I don't understand why tell me always authentication failed

Comment: @Alessandro sounds like the app is failing to authenticate itself with the servers. It's possible that they wrote the app to check what system was running it. Hence, it sees it is an invalid OS and rejects you on startup. I'm going to guess that you'll need some kind of workaround for that. Probably one involving emulation. Plus, this is all assuming it isn't just a bug in the app's recent updates.

Comment: No, I have a nexus 5 with lineage and works perfectly, it's something else

Comment: @Alessandro Like I said, it might just check which OS it is running on to prevent forms of "piracy" or "cheating". Might be some kind of legal thing. I know they've been trying heavily to crack down on cheaters so it's probably setting off an anti-cheat detector thinking your running on a non-phone OS. Unfortunately, that's something the writers of the program put into the app and so without going to them or decompiling the game, we can only experiment/speculate as to what the issue is.