# Can a LG Ice Cream Smart run Pokemon GO?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have an LG Ice Cream Smart. It runs VLIVE, but I'm not sure if it's going to run PKMN Go.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 6):

Your device is very much borderline, in terms of it's specifications. It would likely not be able to run the game in any playable fashion.

If you visit the [Pokemon Go Store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en) while on the device, it will likely tell you as much.

The [Pokemon Go Specifications](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices) list the following requirements:

> - Android 4.4 or above
> - Preferred resolution of 720x1280 pixels (Not optimized for tablet)
> - Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
> - GPS and Location Services
> - Rooted devices are not supported

The LG Ice Cream Smart has the [following specifications](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/lg-ice-cream-smart-2346):

- **Display:** 320x480 pixels
- **Processor:** 1.2Ghz Quad-Core
- **RAM:** 1GB
- **Android Version:** 4.4

The Ice Cream Smart's Android version is the oldest version supported by Pokemon Go, The processor is over 4 years old, and the display resolution is markedly less than what is 'preferred'.

To top it off, [at least 2GB RAM is recommended](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/275701/28182) for the game to run smoothly.

I've personally seen the game running on a 5 year old Samsung tablet and it is far from a smooth experience: the entire game lags, and sometimes completely crashes when too much is happening on-screen. So suffice to say, even if you could get it working I doubt it would be very enjoyable. I'd recommend upgrading to a newer device.